# How to write regular expression in Nginx location default file to map port to proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I had gone through too many answers on stackoverflow but not able to figure it out how to write regex for my requirement.
Here my http://server/xyz/1234/1233/8080/  I have used the following regex location to redirect the above http://server/xyz/1234/1233/8080/  to 127.0.0.1:8080, but it is giving me 404 Not Found Error.

I am writing this location block in default file.

```
 location ~ ^/xyz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/
 {
    rewrite ^/xyz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$ break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
 }
```

I don't know where I am making wrong because I have used it like as said

- **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of line respectively.
- **`(.*)`** - Represents first capturing group matching everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three capturing groups in your `rewrite` directive:

```
^/xyz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)/$
      ↑        ↑        ↑
      first    second   third
```

but you trying to use first group as upstream port. Anyway, you don't need any `rewrite` rule here. You can just declare named group in location and use match as nginx variable, like this:

```
location ~ ^/xyz/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(?<my_port>[0-9]+)/$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:$my_port;
}
```